# iOS PresentModalViewController not working

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am inside a root view controller. and then allocate the secondviewcontroller

```
         SecondViewControl *second=[[SecondViewControl alloc] init];
         [self presentModalViewController:second animated:NO];
```

The second viewcontroller 's view not showing up

AddSubView method works though.
             [self.view addSubView:second.view];

why presetModalViewController is not working?

Comment: Post your loadView code in SecondViewControl

Comment: Your prior question was re `IBOutlet` for your NIB. If you're using NIBs, then Tim's suggestion is good approach. If you're not using NIBs, then Oscar is right that we should see your `loadView` code.

Comment: I modified to use NIB file to load second, but same result. The second's view is not presented.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'll allocate the `SecondViewControl` with a .xib file that actually defines the user interface. Consider using a line like this (broken for readability):

```
SecondViewControl *second = [[SecondViewControl alloc]
                             initWithNibName:@"SecondView" 
                             bundle:nil];
```

Without the accompanying .xib to define the view, you may be left with a view controller that doesn't have the necessary properties set to actually support user interaction, and so `presentModalViewController:` may have trouble there.

Comment: But then it should present a white blank view anyway. So that's not the problem. I wouldn't encourage beginners to use XIB files anyways.

Comment: @H2CO3 not nibs? then storyboards, I presume, forfeiting the 20% pre iOS 5 users?

Comment: @RobertRyan no. Not anything like that. You shouldn't use these tools until you are not able to create a complete UI entirely in code, as these technologies are confusing and not suitable for dynamic UI development.

Comment: @H2CO3 Got it. I respectfully disagree, but I certainly understand your position and rationale. I would suggest that Jason describe, though, whether he used Interface Builder or not (and given that his previous question was re `IBOutlet` for his XIB, I wouldn't assume he's not using XIBs). If so, he should say whether it's via NIB or Storyboard. If not, show us his `loadView` code.

Comment: I'd have to side with RobertRyan on this one, but I too understand the merits of your argument, @H2CO3. Furthermore, you're right - my original answer doesn't really address his problem. Good catch :)